# c++ std::exception "what()" message will always only print "std::exception" in a custom exception - why can't I get it to print the contents?

Tags: c++, exception, inheritance, c++98, object-slicing

if I do this:

```
//... in .h header:

class MyCustomException : public std::exception{
  private:
    string message;

  public:
    MyCustomException (string msg); //in .cpp implements "message = msg"
    ~MyCustomException() throw(){ }
    string what(); //implemented to return message.

}
```

```
//... other code ... in cpp:

if (<blah blah blah>){
  throw MyCustomException("I want to see THIS message when I fail ... but I don't...");
}

//... more code, in cpp:

//try{<blah...>}
catch(const:: std::exception& e){
   cout << e.what() << endl << flush; //just prints "std::exception" ... same if I use "cerr" instead of cout.
}
```

Important notes before replying:

The computer the code is on doesn't have outside communication, so I typed this ... so if there is small obvious typos, know I probably have it correct.

Due to my company's legacy industry equipment, I am stuck with C++98, so do not have access to `std::current_exception` which is with a later version like C++11, I think.

However, I can get `#include <cxxabi.h>` to work, which allows me to `<demangle>(__cxxabivl::__cxa_current_exception_type()->name())` ... but that is still just the name of `MyCustomException`, not its `what()` message.

I *could* try to catch each individual exception and print its `what()` message ... but there should be a way to do it easier, right?

I found the documentation confusing and only really found a `type_info*` that I don't think points to the actual original exception object (wherein I could theoretically extract the proper `what()` message).

Is there a way to add a generic `<T>` to be used in a `catch` for any exception so that I can print `MyCustomException` object's message, and not its super super parent's (i.e. `std::exception`) virtual `what()` message? I tried but it didn't work.

Note: Yes, I use `catch(const std::exception e)` ... yet the "Object Slicing" problem of printing the parent still occurs.

Note: If I catch `MyCustomException`, I get the proper message.

Comment: Please note that the [`what`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception/what) function is supposed to return a `const char*`. And it needs to be `const` qualified.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not experiencing "object slicing" since you are not catching the `exception` by value.

[`std::exception::what()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception/what) is a `virtual` method, but you are simply not overriding it correctly, which is why `MyCustomException::what()` is not being called as expected.  If you were using C++11 or later, you could use the `override` keyword to catch this mistake at compile-time, but that option is not available in C++98.

`MyCustomException::what()` needs to be declared like the following in C++98 to override `std::exception::what()`:

```cpp
const char* what() const throw()
```

Example:

```cpp
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class MyCustomException : public std::exception {
public:
    MyCustomException(const std::string& msg) throw() : message(msg) {}
    virtual ~MyCustomException() throw() {}

    const char* what() const throw() { return message.c_str(); }

private:
    std::string message;
};

int main() {
    try {
        throw MyCustomException(
            "I want to see THIS message when I fail ... but I don't...");
    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << '\n';
    }
}
```

Output:

```
I want to see THIS message when I fail ... but I don't...
```

Comment: @Eugene Jeez, missed that. Editing

Comment: That makes sense now! Ugh - I used to have const char* ... I don't remember why I switched to string but I'll switch back. Thanks so much

Comment: @Andy Glad it cleared it up! You're welcome!

Comment: Thanks again. For anyone else: I just had to do a few other tweaks to match the code format of Ted's answer above:
-add virtual to the destructor
-add "const throw()" to the "what()" function.

Now it is working :)